# Efficient search of several strings in a text file

Tags: bash, grep, processing-efficiency

I use **egrep** to look for exact matches of several strings in a very long file ( 1 million of lines):

```
egrep "\<string1\>|<\string2\>" my_file
```

But it takes too many time even to find just two strings. It seems that it look for every string along the total lines of the file even when it finds an occurrence. 
Indeed, I know that the file contains just one occurence of each string. 
Then I would like to know whow to force egrep to stop looking for a string once it finds an occurence of it and look for the next one of the list. Or if there is another way to do that efficiently.

Thanks.

Comment: How many strings do you want to look for? A handful or something like a few thousand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `-m` option that limits the number of matches:

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
     Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

You can't use it directly with your complex pattern, though, because then you'll only get 1 line for all subpatterns. What you can do is loop over your subpatterns calling `fgrep -m 1`:

```
for pat in $patterns; do
    fgrep -m 1 $pat my_file
done
```

P.S. Another option is to use the complex pattern as you do and specify the number of matches equal to the number of subpatterns, but that'll result in slower comparison for each file line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it with --max-count=NUM

Comment: Aside: Given the OP knows that every string occurs at most one time per file, the average speedup from `--max-count=1` is only 200%.

Comment: I think the complex pattern w/ matches equal to number of subpatterns will actually be fastest; see my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

How you should optimize the search depends on what algorithm your grep implementation uses. The "traditional" algorithm for egrep is to compile the pattern into a deterministic finite automaton. If you don't know what that is, don't worry: the important thing is that the compilation takes a little while, but once that's done it's quite fast, and its speed doesn't depend on the complexity of the pattern it's looking for. In fact, once the compilation is done egrep is actually faster than fgrep -- meaning that fgrep is fastest on small files, egrep is fastest on large files.

At least, that's the situation for the traditional implementations of [ef]grep. I think most modern implementations are adaptive, and will switch algorithms depending on the situation (e.g. I think modern fgreps will switch into compiled DFA mode for large enough files). To find out what's fastest for your implementation(s), you really need to try some timed experiments.

I can give you a few recommendations, though: First, avoid running the search more than once (e.g. running fgrep for each word), because that'll mean scanning the file multiple times. Second, don't worry about minimizing the number of strings it's searching for, because if you're in the best possible mode that won't matter anyway. Third, use @Lev's suggestion of `-m` to make it stop after it's found what it needs to (although I'm pretty sure that'll be single search for both words with `-m2`).

Comment: A very nice answer, thank you. Made me finally go and look up DFA's :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe this one is faster:

```
grep -e '<pattern1>' -e '<pattern2>' -e '<pattern3>' your_file
```

`-F` also may speed things up, I think your patterns aren't really patterns. Also, I think if your output is colored grep has no choice but to look for all patterns.

Comment: I replaced the word pattern by string it's better :)
I have to use egrep because I avoid looping throw the array containing searched strings. Then I just use parameter expension to get then as I written. And finally use egrep to find these ones.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you need `egrep`. How is it better than `grep -F -e 'string1' -e 'string2' -e 'string3' your_file`. Have you tried it, BTW?

Comment: And yes, as Lev suggests, adding `-m 2` to this command line should improve things too, I didn't realize at first you have only one matching line for each pattern, not only one pattern per line.